# Exception in check cookies .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

In the constructor of my controller I checking whether there is a cookie, but i have a System.NullReferenceException, what is wrong?

```
public CartController()
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["cart"] != null)
        {
            //do something
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `Request` object isn't properly initialized at that point in the life cycle of the controller. This code probably shouldn't go in the *constructor* of your controller. Rather try placing it in an action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.Cookies["cart"] != null)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

If you want to share this code across multiple actions, try creating an internal helper method, and then calling it from your actions, like this:

```
private void InitCart()
{
    if (Request.Cookies["cart"] != null)
    {
        //do something
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    InitCart();
}
```

Comment: What if I want to put the data of cookies in a private variable in constructor?

Comment: @Buboon It's hard to say without seeing more code, but really you probably shouldn't. MVC `Controller`'s are supposed to be stateless. If you need to save some data during a single request, just store it in a local variable, not in a instance property/field. If you have to save some data between requests, you should probably store it in the `Session`, `TempData`, a back-end database, or some other place, depending on the nature of the data.

Comment: In constructor I cerialize cookie and save it in private variable.
In other methods i work whit this variable and save result in coockies.

Comment: @Buboon Deserialize it to a local variable at the start of your action, manipulate that variable, pass it as a parameter to any methods you may need, and serialize it back to the `Cookies` collection at the end of your action.

Comment: @Buboon Glad to help. If you have any more issues in implementing that solution, you can always ask again on SO. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Action Filter rather than place your code in the constructor, that might help you avoid repetition in your code.

Add an attribute that derives from `ActionFilterAttribute` to your controller:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public CartController()
{
}
```

This filter then intercepts every action.

```
 public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute

 {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
          var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
          // Do something with request....
      }

      public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
      {
          // Do anything else if you feel like it.
      }
 }
```